# How do I model the pressure as a function of time induced by flow in a multi-compartment model?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

I am trying to think about what seems like a basic physics problem, but I don't have any real background in fluid dynamics and only a bit of an undergrad background in other kinds of physics (though I have a pretty strong background up to a graduate level in mathematics). I am also fairly experienced in many kinds of computational modelling in case this is not solvable analyticallly.

Assume that at time 0 the pressure is at equillibrium across the structure in the diagram. I don't know the best way to write this assumption, but the opening in $P_1$ is open to, say, a really large box such that change in L(t) has a negligable effect on the pressure in this box. I would like to express the pressures $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ as a function of L(t) a movable barrier. I would like to assume $L(t) = (cos(t) + 1)/2$ (or $(sin(t) + 1)/2$ or whichever reparameterization makes things easiest). I know I need to use the Bernoulli principle. I know how to write many expressions that seem useful, like the volume over time in compartment 3, the pressure assuming an ideal gas, and so on, but I don't know how to combine these things. I'm sure there are many ambiguities in the problem as I've stated it, but hopefully it's enough that I could be pointed in the right direction.